# Get signature option in DocuSign envelop

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

I am sending an envelop to user from DocuSign account. In my application I want to get URL for an envelop in postman. I am getting an URL but once I open the URL signature option is not coming.

I am calling below createRecipientView endpoint.

URL: [https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopId}/views/recipient](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/envelopes/%7BenvelopId%7D/views/recipient)

In request body sending:
recipient_id, userName, email, authenticationMethod, returnUrl

I am getting URL for an envelop but signature tab is not there to sign on envelop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the signature tab to the envelope in the API call where you make  the envelope. It's part of the recipient object, because tabs are tied to recipients.

Here is what this JSON may look like, in this case using anchor strings to position (you can also used fixed positioning with `xPosition` and `yPosition` instead)

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this document set",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "' > $request_data
            cat $doc1_base64 >> $request_data
            printf '",
            "name": "Order acknowledgement",
            "fileExtension": "html",
            "documentId": "1"
        },
        {
            "documentBase64": "' >> $request_data
            cat $doc2_base64 >> $request_data
            printf '",
            "name": "Battle Plan",
            "fileExtension": "docx",
            "documentId": "2"
        },
        {
            "documentBase64": "' >> $request_data
            cat $doc3_base64 >> $request_data
            printf '",
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "documentId": "3"
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "carbonCopies": [
            {
                "email": "'"${CC_EMAIL}"'",
                "name": "'"${CC_NAME}"'",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2"
            }
        ],
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "'"${SIGNER_EMAIL}"'",
                "name": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "anchorString": "**signature_1**",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "anchorString": "/sn1/",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```